# Exception calling "SqlBackup" with "1" argument(s): "Backup failed for Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am getting this error on SQL2012R2 I work on SQL2016 with out a hic

> Exception calling "SqlBackup" with "1" argument(s): "Backup failed for
>   Server 'DEVSQLD01'. "

Script:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $serverName


$dbName = "Staging-Xtra"

$timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss
$targetPath = $backupDirectory + "\" + $dbName + "_" + $timestamp + ".bak"

$smoBackup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
$smoBackup.Action = "Database"
$smoBackup.BackupSetDescription = "Full Backup of " + $dbName
$smoBackup.BackupSetName = $dbName + " Backup"
$smoBackup.Database = $dbName
$smoBackup.MediaDescription = "Disk"
$smoBackup.Devices.AddDevice($targetPath, "File")
$smoBackup.SqlBackup($server)
```

> Exception calling "SqlBackup" with "1" argument(s): "Backup failed for
>   Server 'DEVSQLD01'. "

Comment: What is $backupDirectory here? And why not just use T-SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I might have had the same problem. It had to do with permissions to the destination folder for the SQL Server Service Account.

PowerShell is just submitting T-SQL to SQL Server to execute, so the account running the script must have the requisite permissions. Once I gave it read/write everything worked well